# Edit text "No Payment Information Required"

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout

In the Checkout Onepage section of the billing I have a payment switch method
a (button) Pay Pal or b) No Payment Information Required
I need to translate (Dutch) the text of No Payment Information Required.
I tried a nl_NL page and several Mag files, no result.
Can someone shine a light please

Comment: Did you tried inline translation?

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that funtion. When it reads Location: Heading level 2
Scope: Mage_Checkout
Where can I find that location?

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Answer (score 4):

'No Payment Information Required' is actually a payment method.
You can find the text in `System->Configuration->Payment methods`.
Use the store selector from the top left side of the page to change the config scope to the store view you need and translate the title of the method.